# MS Word 2010 - keyboard shortcut for replace that uses selected text

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

When I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> my selected text is put into the find side panel, but I need to do extra mouse steps to do a replace.

When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> I get a replace dialog box, but it ignores my selected text.

Is there a way to have a keyboard shortcut that opens a replace box directly, putting selected text into the find field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to get your desired effect, but if even that's too much then you can [make a macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff604039(v=office.14).aspx) to do it all in one go.

Perhaps map it to the unused <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> key combination.

```
Sub QuickReplace()
    Selection.Copy
    Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
    Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard
    Selection.Find.Text = DataObj.GetText
    Dialogs(wdDialogEditReplace).Show
End Sub
```

If you receive a "User-defined type not defined" you are [missing the reference to Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/paste-clipboard-contents-vba/). If its not listed, add `C:\Windows\System32\FM20.dll` or `C:\Windows\FM20.dll` as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have a keyboard shortcut that opens a replace box
>   directly, putting selected text into the find field?

That's the default behaviour with Word 20**13** when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Perhaps this is of interest to you even though you explicitly mentioned Word 20**10**.

Comment: Is there a way to set this as the default behavior in Word 2010?

Comment: @MarkKosmowski: Not that I know of.

Comment: @MarkKosmowski Didn't the [macro solution](http://superuser.com/a/870195/32245) work for you? Another solution would be to install [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com) and to write a script which would intercept Ctrl+H and do what you want. I could try writing a script if that was a viable solution and see whether it works at all.